# Como insiro dados na coluna de chave estrangeira na tabela com Django usando form.html

Tags: python, django, formulário

Criei duas tabelas uma para cliente e outra para fatura
tabela de faturas tem chave estrangeira da tabela de clientes
neste caso pretendo criar um formulário htm para enviar dados na tabela da fatura  que contém uma chave estrangeira, mas tentei enviar dados e ele não aceita sempre dá erro descobri que é na coluna da chave estrangeira que não recebe dados, não sei como referenciar dados de clientes nesta tabela de faturas  usando formulário html no django

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Quero enviar dados para tabela na base de dados usando formulario html. Nesta tabela que pretendo enviar dados tem uma coluna da chave estrangeira, a minh apergunta é como devo enviar dados para esssa tabela na base de dados usando formulario não inline no django

Comment: Por favor atualize seu post com o código que você tem para os modelos das duas tabelas em questão, código do form e do template.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, consegui resolver veja o codigo que postei na resposta, caso tiver mais opções do codigo vai ajudar muito

Answer (score -4):

```
  def atualizar(request, contador):
    lista = factura.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador)
    cont=cliente.objects.filter(contador=contador).first() # Aqui é onde vai carregar dados de cliente
    if request.POST:
        
        data1=request.POST['data1']
        factura_nr=request.POST['factura_nr']
        data2=request.POST['data2']
        consumo=request.POST['consumo']
        
        dados = factura(
            contador=cont, # Aqui onde vai inseriri no chave estrangeira
            consumo=consumo,
            data1=data1,
            data2=data2,
            factura_nr=factura_nr

        )
        dados.save()
    
    return render(request, 'tabela.html', {'lista': lista, 'cont':cont})
```